# How can I map 0 to 1 and 1 to -1?

Tags: c#, python, math, hlsl

I am trying to convert the value 0 to 1 and 1 to -1, but without using if statements. I tried to do some math to map it to a new range but I am not able to do it for both parameters.

Is this doable?

It has to do this without hardcoded values in a collection though, so for example:

```
initial = 0 or 1;
final_value = (initial + 1) * -1;
```

So final value will be mapped to 1 or -1 depending on the initial value, using the same equation.

EDIT: I am basically trying to get rid of the `if` statement because this is shader code and my friend at work (shader programmer) said `if` statements slow down the execution so it's better to do things uniformly. Not sure if it makes sense.

Comment: With a simple dictionary if you wish. You have to tell the exact constraints.

Comment: Why did you tag this with *two* languages? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Either a list or a dictionary would let you map two integer values to two other values with ease, but you have left this rather thin on details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
1-(2*variable_value)
```

would give you those values ... but there is a strong chance this is not what you want ... because its really hard to tell what you want

since you have clarified that you want speed for shaders I figured I would add this info

```
In [3]: %timeit x= 1 if not random.randint(0,1) else -1 #if statement
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 us per loop

In [4]: %timeit x= 1-(2*random.randint(0,1)) #simple math
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 us per loop

In [5]: %timeit x= [1,-1][random.randint(0,1)] #array lookup
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 us per loop

In [7]: %timeit x= arr[random.randint(0,1)]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 us per loop
```

I actually was a little surprised that the array lookup was slower (Actually only if you dont already have the array constructed)

Comment: As would `[1, -1][variable_value]` and `{0: 1, 1: -1}[variable_value]`. The former will work in C# too, no doubt.

Comment: yup .... there are alot of ways to skin this cat and its not clear from OP what is really intended(I +1'd Tims answer)

Comment: Would this equation not return 3 for 1?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Thanks, what's `us` unit? Also is this HLSL? Not sure if that matters.

Comment: microseconds is what us is

Comment: Lookups are likely to be even slower in a shader. Any kind of memory read should be avoided if at all possible (that's why there are built-ins to group 4+ reads, the performance impact for that many is huge). The real question is whether the HLSL compiler or the driver/card will optimize the `if` into math, which is probably happening here. I'd go with the math just to be safe.

Comment: I find it funny that the inline `if` method is one of the fastest, since this was explicitly being avoided.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am not an expert in shaders that's why I am following his advice.

Answer (score 9):

In Python:

```
arr = [1, -1]
mapped = arr[n]
```